# MySQL select count only new id's for each year

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct, having

I have a MySQL table that looks like this

```
    id   |   client_id   |    date
  --------------------------------------
     1   |       12      | 02/02/2008
     2   |       15      | 12/06/2008
     3   |       23      | 11/12/2008
     4   |       12      | 18/01/2009
     5   |       12      | 03/03/2009
     6   |       18      | 02/07/2009
     7   |       23      | 08/09/2010
     8   |       18      | 02/10/2010
     9   |       21      | 30/11/2010
```

What I am trying to do is get the number of new clients for each year. 2008 has 3 new clients(12,15,23), 2009 has 1 new client(18) and 2010 has 1 new client(21).

So far I have this query that gives me the distinct clients for each year, that is 3 for 2008, 2 for 2009 and 3 for 2010.

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) FROM table GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Presumably, your date column uses a date data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a subquery to get the first year of every `client_id` grouped by `client_id`, and then count the occurrence of `client_id` grouped by year, so:

```
SELECT COUNT(client_id), YEAR_MIN FROM (
    SELECT client_id, MIN(YEAR(date)) AS YEAR_MIN 
    FROM   table 
    GROUP BY client_id) AS T
GROUP BY YEAR_MIN
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0371f4e/2)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to count the first date a client appears in the table. In other words, the row for which no other row exists with an earlier date and the same client. You can do this with an *exclusion join*.

Then you can count them per year as you're doing now.

```
SELECT YEAR(t.date) AS yr, COUNT(t.client_id) AS client_count
FROM (
  SELECT t1.client_id, t1.date
  FROM mytable AS t1
  LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON (t1.client_id=t2.client_id AND t1.date > t2.date)
  WHERE t2.client_id IS NULL) AS t
GROUP BY yr
```

You should store dates using the DATE data type, which uses YYYY-MM-DD format. You won't be able to do `>` comparisons if your dates are stored as strings in DD-MM-YYYY format.

Comment: Old school. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,client_id INT NOT NULL
,date INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,12,2008),
(2,15,2008),
(3,23,2008),
(4,12,2009),
(5,12,2009),
(6,18,2009),
(7,23,2010),
(8,18,2010),
(9,21,2010);

SELECT year
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT client_id, MIN(date) year FROM my_table GROUP BY client_id ) x 
 GROUP 
    BY year;
+------+-------+
| year | total |
+------+-------+
| 2008 |     3 |
| 2009 |     1 |
| 2010 |     1 |
+------+-------+
```